# Enum Ploblem alway value how?

Tags: c#, enums

```
public enum FrameStatus
{
    NotReport = 0,
    NormalStatus = 1,
    NotNormalstatus = 2
}
```

but alway FrameStatus.NormalStatus how?

```
public FrameStatus FrameReportStatus(int Framid, string Timebet)
{
    foreach (FrameCam fc in al)
    {
        if (fc.Timebet == Timebet && fc.IdFrame == Framid)
        {
           if ((int)fc.status == 1) fc.status = FrameStatus.NormalStatus;
           else if ((int)fc.status == 2) fc.status = FrameStatus.NotNormalstatus;
           else fc.status = FrameStatus.NotReport;
           return fc.status;
        }
    }
    return FrameStatus.NotReport;
}
```

my complete classs

```
class FrameCam
{
    private ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    public string strConnect;

    public FrameStatus status = FrameStatus.NormalStatus;
    public string Timebet;
    public int IdFrame;

    public FrameCam()
    {

    }
    public FrameCam(string st, string bt)
    {
        strConnect = st;
        Timebet = bt;
        LoadtoList();
    }

    public FrameStatus GetFramStatus(int Framid, string timebet)
    {
        foreach (FrameCam fc in al)
        {
            if (Framid == fc.IdFrame && timebet == fc.Timebet)
            {
                return fc.status;
            }
        }
        return FrameStatus.NotReport;
    }
    private void LoadtoList()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlDataReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            string query =
                "SELECT * FROM FrameReport WHERE convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 101) = convert(varchar, DateTimeSign, 101) AND TimeSignBeetWeen='" +this.Timebet+"'";

            conn = new SqlConnection(this.strConnect);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand();
            sc.CommandText = query;
            sc.Connection = conn;
            sr = sc.ExecuteReader();
            while (sr.Read())
            {
                FrameCam fc = new FrameCam();
                fc.Timebet = sr["TimeSignBeetWeen"].ToString();
                fc.IdFrame = (int)sr["IdFrame"];
                if ((int)sr["Status"] == (int)FrameStatus.NormalStatus)
                {
                    status = FrameStatus.NormalStatus;
                }
                if ((int)sr["Status"] == (int)FrameStatus.NotNormalstatus)
                {
                    status = FrameStatus.NotNormalstatus;
                }
                else status = FrameStatus.NotReport;

                al.Add(fc);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null) sr.Close();
            if (conn != null) conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public FrameStatus FrameReportStatus(int Framid, string Timebet)
    {
        foreach (FrameCam fc in al)
        {
            if (fc.Timebet == Timebet && fc.IdFrame == Framid)
            {
                if ((int)fc.status == 1) fc.status = FrameStatus.NormalStatus;
                else if ((int)fc.status == 2) fc.status = FrameStatus.NotNormalstatus;
                else fc.status = FrameStatus.NotReport;
                return fc.status;
            }
        }
        return FrameStatus.NotReport;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really not at all obvious what you mean by "alway FrameStatus.NormalStatus how". It would help if you could give a complete program, say what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: it also looks like the code will always return FrameStatus.NotReport the way it is currently written

Comment: @monkey_boys: It seems you either don't listen to or don't understand the comments from people trying to help you, and you keep doing the same thing. I've said it before in English, but here goes Google Translate: ฉัน รู้ว่าภาษาอังกฤษไม่ใช่ภาษาแม่ของคุณและที่ต้องยากจะแสดงสิ่งที่คุณต้องการ แต่โปรดลองหนักขึ้นเพื่อให้คำถามของท่านชัดเจนและจะนำเข้าจำนวนมากราย ละเอียดเพิ่มเติม

Comment: Also, โชว์โค้ดสำหรับ FrameCam class และวางไว้ในคำตอบเดิมของคุณไม่เป็นคำตอบใหม่. Hopefully meaning: Add the code for the FrameCam class, and edit your original answer, don't add a new one.

Comment: It's disgusting to see this question marked down, it's perfectly valid and solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning anything to fc.Status within LoadToList and the initialize for FrameCam's 'status' field is "FrameStatus.NormalStatus". If you update the code in LoadToList to assign to fc.status (instead of this.status, as is shown here) then it should work as you expect.

As a side note, LoadToList should be a static method, which would have mitigated this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use a debugger.  Step through the code.

The code is not taking the path you think it is taking.

If you do not know how to step through code in a debugger, you **MUST** learn.

**This is not an optional skill for a computer programmer.**